# How can I create a sliding cursor with a particular shape in PsychToolBox?

Tags: matlab, cursor, sliding, psychtoolbox

It supposed to be look like this http://prntscr.com/dezwb6. red rectangle should move as the cursor move.

it supposed to be created with while loop but ı have tried with for loop

```
 for x=1:1366 % my screen's length
        if( x > 383) & (x < 983)  % in order to keep cursor within the borders of the green rectangle
                  cLeft=x; % I determine the left s,de of the red rectangele
            cRight=cLeft+20; % with using lef side I determine right side

            cTop=374; %  I determine top side with using the same values with green rectangle
            cBottom=394;% bottom border of the red rectangle

            RedRect=[cLeft,cTop,cRight,cBottom]; % I determine the all sides of the rectangle

            Red=[255 50 50]%I determine the color of the rect

          Screen('FillRect',myWindow,Red,RedRect); % I try to create a rectangular %with using cursor' position bu it didn't work:/

        end 

    end
```

Comment: I suggest you elaborate more on your approach and what didn't work for you to make it easier for others to understand your problem.

Comment: Please don’t deface your question, as it invalidates the existing answer. If you really need to delete this question e.g. for IP reasons, contact Stack Exchange to have it permanently deleted from the database. I understand that you can also have the question unlinked from your account. Thank you!

Comment: You are right, this is part of a project, for this reason I distort the question I send request for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is still helpful. I wrote a function for exactly that with vertical line called [slideScale](https://github.com/JAQuent/functions-for-matlab/blob/master/slideScale.m). If you want to see how it works see the [test script](https://github.com/JAQuent/functions-for-matlab/blob/master/test_slideScale.m).

Code:

```
function [position, RT, answer] = slideScale(screenPointer, question, rect, endPoints, varargin)
%SLIDESCALE This funtion draws a slide scale on a PSYCHTOOLOX 3 screen and returns the
% position of the slider in pixel as well as the rection time and if an answer was given.
%
%   Usage: [position, secs] = slideScale(ScreenPointer, question, center, rect, endPoints, varargin)
%   Mandatory input:
%    ScreenPointer  -> pointer to the window
%    question       -> Text string containing the question
%    rect           -> Double contatining the screen size.
%                      Obtained with [myScreen, rect] = Screen('OpenWindow', 0);
%    endPoints      -> Cell containg the two text string of the left and right
%                      end of the scala. Exampe: endPoints = {'left, 'right'};
%
%   Varargin:
%    'linelength'    -> An integer specifying the lengths of the ticks in
%                       pixels. The default is 10.
%    'width'         -> An integer specifying the width of the scala leine in
%                       pixels. The default is 3.
%    'scalalength'   -> Double value between 0 and 1 for the length of the
%                       scale. The default is 0.9.
%    'scalaposition' -> Double value between 0 and 1 for the position of the
%                       scale. 0 is top and 1 is bottom.
%    'device'        -> A string specifying the response device. Either 'mouse' 
%                       or 'keyboard'. The default is 'mouse'.
%    'responsekey'   -> String containing name of the key from the keyboard to log the
%                       response. Example. The default is 'return'.
%    'slidecolor'    -> Vector for the color value of the slider [r g b] 
%                       from 0 to 255. The dedult is red [255 0 0].
%    'scalacolor'    -> Vector for the color value of the scale [r g b] 
%                       from 0 to 255.The dedult is black [0 0 0].
%    'aborttime'     -> Double specifying the time in seconds after which
%                       the function should be aborted. In this case no
%                       answer is saved. The default is 8 secs.
%    'image'         -> An image saved in a uint8 matrix. Use
%                       imread('image.png') to load an image file.  
%
%   Output:
%    'position'      -> Deviation from zero in percentage, 
%                       with -100 <= position <= 100 to indicate left-sided
%                       and right-sided deviation.
%    'RT'            -> Reaction time in milliseconds.
%    'answer'        -> If 0, no answer has been given. Otherwise this
%                       variable is 1.
%
%   Author: Joern Alexander Quent
%   e-mail: alexander.quent@rub.de
%   Version history:
%                    1.0 - 01/04/2016 - First draft
%                    1.1 - 02/18/2016 - Added abort time and option to
%                    choose between mouse and key board
%                    1.2 - 05/10/2016 - End points will be aligned to end
%                    ticks
%                    1.3 - 06/01/2016 - Added the possibility to display an
%                    image



%% Return error if in multi display mode!
screens       = Screen('Screens');
if length(screens) > 1
    error('Multi display mode not supported.');
end

%% Parse input arguments
% Default values
center        = round([rect(3) rect(4)]/2);
lineLength    = 10;
width         = 3;
scalaLength   = 0.9;
scalaPosition = 0.8;
sliderColor    = [255 0 0];
scaleColor    = [0 0 0];
device        = 'mouse';
aborttime     = 8;
responseKey   = KbName('return');
drawImage     = 0;

i = 1;
while(i<=length(varargin))
    switch lower(varargin{i})
        case 'linelength'
            i             = i + 1;
            lineLength    = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'width'
            i             = i + 1;
            width         = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'scalalength'
            i             = i + 1;
            scalaLength   = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'scalaposition'
            i             = i + 1;
            scalaPosition = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'device' 
            i             = i + 1;
            device = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'responsekey'
            i             = i + 1;
            responseKey   = KbName(varargin{i});
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'slidecolor'
            i             = i + 1;
            sliderColor    = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'scalacolor'
            i             = i + 1;
            scaleColor    = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'aborttime'
            i             = i + 1;
            aborttime     = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
        case 'image'
            i             = i + 1;
            image         = varargin{i};
            i             = i + 1;
            imageSize     = size(image);
            stimuli       = Screen('MakeTexture', screenPointer, image);
            drawImage     = 1; 
    end
end

% Sets the default key depending on choosen device
if strcmp(device, 'mouse')
    responseKey   = 1; % X mouse button
end

%% Coordinates of scale lines and text bounds
midTick    = [center(1) rect(4)*scalaPosition - lineLength - 5 center(1) rect(4)*scalaPosition  + lineLength + 5];
leftTick   = [rect(3)*(1-scalaLength) rect(4)*scalaPosition - lineLength rect(3)*(1-scalaLength) rect(4)*scalaPosition  + lineLength];
rightTick  = [rect(3)*scalaLength rect(4)*scalaPosition - lineLength rect(3)*scalaLength rect(4)*scalaPosition  + lineLength];
horzLine   = [rect(3)*scalaLength rect(4)*scalaPosition rect(3)*(1-scalaLength) rect(4)*scalaPosition];
textBounds = [Screen('TextBounds', screenPointer, endPoints{1}); Screen('TextBounds', screenPointer, endPoints{2})];
if drawImage == 1
    rectImage  = [center(1) - imageSize(2)/2 rect(4)*(scalaPosition - 0.2) - imageSize(1) center(1) + imageSize(2)/2 rect(4)*(scalaPosition - 0.2)];
    if rect(4)*(scalaPosition - 0.2) - imageSize(1) < 0
        error('The height of the image is too large. Either lower your scale or use the smaller image.');
    end
end

%% Loop for scale loop
t0                         = GetSecs;
answer                     = 0;
while answer == 0
    [x,y,buttons,focus,valuators,valinfo] = GetMouse(screenPointer, 1);
    if x > rect(3)*scalaLength
        x = rect(3)*scalaLength;
    elseif x < rect(3)*(1-scalaLength)
        x = rect(3)*(1-scalaLength);
    end

    % Draw image if provided
    if drawImage == 1
         Screen('DrawTexture', screenPointer, stimuli,[] , rectImage, 0);
    end

    % Drawing the question as text
    DrawFormattedText(screenPointer, question, 'center', rect(4)*(scalaPosition - 0.1)); 

    % Drawing the end points of the scala as text
    DrawFormattedText(screenPointer, endPoints{1}, leftTick(1, 1) - textBounds(1, 3)/2,  rect(4)*scalaPosition+10, [],[],[],[],[],[],[]); % Left point
    DrawFormattedText(screenPointer, endPoints{2}, rightTick(1, 1) - textBounds(2, 3)/2,  rect(4)*scalaPosition+10, [],[],[],[],[],[],[]); % Right point

    % Drawing the scala
    Screen('DrawLine', screenPointer, scaleColor, midTick(1), midTick(2), midTick(3), midTick(4), width);         % Mid tick
    Screen('DrawLine', screenPointer, scaleColor, leftTick(1), leftTick(2), leftTick(3), leftTick(4), width);     % Left tick
    Screen('DrawLine', screenPointer, scaleColor, rightTick(1), rightTick(2), rightTick(3), rightTick(4), width); % Right tick
    Screen('DrawLine', screenPointer, scaleColor, horzLine(1), horzLine(2), horzLine(3), horzLine(4), width);     % Horizontal line

    % The slider
    Screen('DrawLine', screenPointer, sliderColor, x, rect(4)*scalaPosition - lineLength, x, rect(4)*scalaPosition  + lineLength, width);

    % Flip screen
    onsetStimulus = Screen('Flip', screenPointer);

    % Check if answer has been given
    if strcmp(device, 'mouse')
        secs = GetSecs;
        if buttons(responseKey) == 1
            answer = 1;
        end
    elseif strcmp(device, 'keyboard')
        [keyIsDown, secs, keyCode] = KbCheck;
        if keyCode(responseKey) == 1
            answer = 1;
        end
    else
        error('Unknown device');
    end

    % Abort if answer takes too long
    if secs - t0 > aborttime 
        break
    end
end
%% Calculating the rection time and the position
RT                = (secs - t0)*1000;                                          % converting RT to millisecond
scaleRange        = round(rect(3)*(1-scalaLength)):round(rect(3)*scalaLength); % Calculates the range of the scale
scaleRangeShifted = round((scaleRange)-mean(scaleRange));                      % Shift the range of scale so it is symmetrical around zero
position          = round((x)-mean(scaleRange));                               % Shift the x value according to the new scale
position          = (position/max(scaleRangeShifted))*100;                     % Converts the value to percentage
end
```